# Detect if SharePoint is using the system master page

Tags: 2013, master-page, branding, system-master-page

Is there a way to detect if SharePoint is using the system master page? (just like EditModePanel, or detecting the system master page with javascript..)

Right now I'm using the same master page on both.

What I want is to display the site title in the system masterpage. If you are in `_layouts/settings.aspx` or Site Contents etc., the users does not know where they are (url is the only way to know where you are, and that is not good enought). I don't want to make 2 master pages (maintenance) just for the "navigation title" in the page.

Publishing features are turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from any API calls, why not just modify the master pages to include some javascript that sets a variable telling which master it is

Var master="masters?asps"

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work. If I'm using the same master page for publishing and system master page

Answer (score 0):

how you want to detect. there are couple of ways to check which master page is being used.

if you don’t have the Publishing feature activated navigate to

> http://your_server.com/sites/examples/_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

If you do have the Publishing feature enabled you can go to Master Page on the

> Site Settings page, under Look and Feel category

Or you can take the advantage of CustomMasterUrl or MasterUrl properties of a web.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sharepoint

$web.CustomMasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/nightandday.master"

$web.MasterUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/nightandday.master"

$web.Update()
```

.

Comment: I don't want to set the masterpage. I just want to detect witch master page the page is currently using.

Comment: dont set it, but still you go to that pages you will know which master is being used

Comment: It's possible to make an javascript that detects different "system" pages, but I don't like that approach. Is there a way to detect system pages?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe some basic JavaScript like

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts") > 0) { console.log("This is a system page"); }
```